# Restoring SQL Server Database Command Line Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, sqlcmd

I have a restore database script in a SQL file, and I'm trying to restore a backup generated from one DB to a new DB (that exists). That SQL file is being executed by SQLCMD on the command line. The command window lets me know the restore finished successfully; however, the database is in a restoring state still, and cannot be accessed. Because of that, the rest of my batch process fails. How can I get the database out of the restoring state, and back into an online state so that I can run additional batch process scripts?

I'm using this to do it:

```
restore filelistonly
from disk = 'c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql10.mssqlserver\mssql\backup\olddb.bak'
GO

RESTORE DATABASE NewDB
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\olddb.bak'
WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE,
MOVE 'OldDB' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\newdb.mdf',
MOVE 'OldDB_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\newdb.ldf'
```

Any ideas why my db is still in restoring state if it says it completed successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used NORECOVERY which leaves the database ready to receive diff/log restores

You can remove it above, or simply run this

```
RESTORE DATABASE NewDB WITH RECOVERY
```

See [MSDN RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx), look for "`[ RECOVERY | NORECOVERY | STANDBY ]`" header